# AutoIt pause/continue script function

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to make a function with hotkeys that pauses the script, so it doesn't send anything. But also a function that enables the script again. Here is what I have so far:

```
Func TogglePause()
   $Paused = NOT $Paused

   If $Paused Then ToolTip('Script "Paused"',500,500)

   While $Paused
      Sleep(1)
   WEnd

   ToolTip("")
EndFunc
```

Let's say you're typing <kbd>H</kbd>, the script pauses so it doesn't do anything. Once you press <kbd>J</kbd> the script is enabled again.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the helpfile (HotKeyset)

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("+!d", "ShowMessage") ; Shift-Alt-d

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func TogglePause()
    $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
    While $g_bPaused
        Sleep(100)
        ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
    WEnd
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc   ;==>TogglePause

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate

Func ShowMessage()
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "This is a message.")
EndFunc   ;==>ShowMessage
```

Does this fix your problem?

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "HotKeyPressed")
HotKeySet("1", "HotKeyPressed")
HotKeySet("2", "HotKeyPressed")
HotKeySet("+!d", "HotKeyPressed") ; Shift-Alt-d

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func HotKeyPressed()
    Switch @HotKeyPressed ; The last hotkey pressed.
        Case "{PAUSE}" ; String is the {PAUSE} hotkey.
            $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
            While $g_bPaused
                Sleep(100)
                ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
            WEnd
            ToolTip("")

        Case "1"
            While 1
                Send('F')
                Sleep(500)
            WEnd

        Case "2"
            While 1
                Send('D')
                Sleep(500)
            WEnd

        Case "+!d" ; String is the Shift-Alt-d hotkey.
            MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "This is a message.")

    EndSwitch
EndFunc   ;==>HotKeyPressed
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It doesn't work as intended. Not at all. So I'm going to post my full script to make it even more specific (since it is too long I'll screen shot it) http://imgur.com/TDKlWsx      This script sends "F" instead of "D". So I need a Pause function that pauses the script, so it doesn't send "F" instead of "D" anymore until I press a specific HotKey. For example H. Overall, it doesn't stop the function properly.

Comment: I don't get it! I tried my luck with a second script.

Comment: It sadly doesn't work, but I changed the script so it doesn't look so complicated. Here it is:


HotKeySet("{ESC}","_sende");
While Sleep(1);
WEnd
Func _sende()
 HotKeySet("{ENTER}");
 Send("D{ENTER}");
 HotKeySet("{ENTER}","_enter");
EndFunc

It instantly sends "D" when you press the ESC button. When I combine it with your Pause Func, it still sends "D" when you press the ESC button, so it is not completely paused. I advise you trying this out yourself, so you get better understanding of how it works. It is actually pretty simple.

Comment: You don't understand how this HotKeySet stuff works. My script works the way it should. Da du _sende() geschrieben hast, denke ich, dass du deutsch sprichst. Versuch mal auf deutsch zu beschreiben, was du genau möchtest.

Comment: I don't speak German. "sende" was supposed to be "SendE" instead.

Also there's not much left to explain. It just sends "D" when you press "ESC". But like I said, your Pause func doesn't prevent it from sending "D" when you press "ESC". This is not like any other script. Try it out yourself, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I am revising the answer again to show my new example. This example will send "Q{ENTER}" at the start of the script every time the user hits the enter key. Now, when typing the letter 'b' on the keyboard, it automatically pauses the script and sends the key like normal. Whenever the user types the spacebar, the script is automatically activated again to start sending "Q{ENTER}" again. It can be manually paused/unpaused by using the pause/break key on the keyboard, and the process can be terminated by pressing the escape key.

---

### Code.au3

```
; 1 - If the pause/break button is pressed, activate the togglePause function.
; 2 - If the esc (escape) key is pressed, stop the program.
; 3 - If the Enter key is pressed, run your function.


HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "togglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "quitScript")
HotKeySet("{ENTER}","Enter")
; ADDED TWO HOTKEYS FOR B AND SPACE
HotKeySet("b", "keyPressB")
HotKeySet("{SPACE}", "keyPressSpace")
; This variable is set to leave the program unpaused at start.
global $isPaused = False
; This empty while loops keeps the program active until manually exiting.
While 1
WEnd

; This is a variation of the function you created.
Func Enter()
        ; If the program is unpaused (which it is at start), the program will send the Q then Enter button.
        if $isPaused == false then
            HotKeySet("{ENTER}");
            Send("Q{ENTER}");
            HotKeySet("{ENTER}","Enter")

        ; If the program is paused, it will send JUST the enter button like you are typing normally.
        elseif $isPaused == true then
            HotKeySet("{ENTER}");
            Send("{ENTER}");
            HotKeySet("{ENTER}","Enter")
        EndIf
EndFunc

; ADDED THE TWO FUNCTIONS BELOW TO PROCESS THE B AND SPACE HOTKEYS
Func keyPressB ()
    ; Pauses the program
    $isPaused = true
    ; Sends the b key like you are normally typing
    HotKeySet("b")
    Send("b")
    HotKeySet("b", "keyPressB")
EndFunc

Func keyPressSpace ()
    ; Unpauses the program
    $isPaused = false
    HotKeySet("{space}")
    Send("{SPACE}")
    HotKeySet("{SPACE}", "keyPressSpace")
EndFunc


; Function to pause script
Func togglePause ()
    ; When this function is initiated, the code on the next line 'toggles' the variable to True/False. If the script is unpaused (the $isPaused variable is set to 'False') then the next line will change it to 'True' and vice versa.
    $isPaused = NOT $isPaused
    ; Create a while loop to stall the program
    ; The line below is the same thing as "While $isPaused == True"
    While $isPaused
        ; This code will run constantly until the $isPaused variable is set to 'True'. To make the script do nothing, simply add a sleep command.
         Sleep(250)
    WEnd
EndFunc

Func quitScript ()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Comment: Hey Tim, firstly I really appreciate you two helping me, just so you two know that.


Also,Example One is  not the script I'm looking for.
I don't know about Example Two since when I run it, the script just closes itself automatically.

And no, I'm not running more than one function. I'm only using one function as you can see in the picture http://imgur.com/VH3L2s2.
I basically need a Pause func for the func you can see in the picture.

Comment: When you try it out yourself, you will really know what I'm talking about. Just use my script in the picture, combine it with your Pause func and you will see the script will still send "Q" when you press Enter.

Comment: Would you mind posting it on pastepin? I am at work and my firewall blocks imagur. As for example two, I should apologize. It is an EDIT for example one. Change the hotkeys in example one to look like example two, then change stitchKeyF and switchKeyD to the single switchKey function is the second example.

Comment: Not to be mean, but I already know the script you posted is not the one I'm actually looking for. 

Here: http://pastebin.com/tE8kLemv

Comment: I understand. I'm trying to understand what you ARE looking for so I can potentially help you find it. So for this example, you want to be able to pause the script and press enter normally?

Comment: Yeah, this is ALMOST the way I want it. Thanks so much dude, we are very close.
I  have some problems, some issues which I'm sure are fixable.
I need it to stop the func when I press the "ß" key, so it ONLY disables the func, not renables the func when you press it twice. I also noticed you cannot type the HotKey (for example "ß"), as it only just disables the func. Is there a way to send the key when you type it although it is reserved as a HotKey? I'd need that to  be honest. I also need "Space" to be the key which ONLY RENABLES the func.

Comment: And I need Enter to ONLY RENABLE the func as well. Let's say you type "Hello Worldß", it should be "Hello Worldß" without the "Q" at the end since the "ß" key disabled it. Now let's say you're typing "Hello Worldß I'm big" it'd be "Hello Worldß I'm bigQ" since you typed "Space" which renables the func ONLY. If you'd type "Hello Worldß"; it'd be "Hello Worldß" as we know, but when you begin the next sentence without typing "ß" it'd be "Someday I mayQ". You get what I mean? I know this is very confusing, but I'd be so thankful if you solve this for me.

Comment: Sure, check out my revised answer above. Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: So far the script is actually pretty good. There is something that really bothers me, that when you type "ß", it actually doesn't send "ß" since it is reserved as a HotKey. And also "ß" should actually really only disable the func, not renable it by pressing it twice in a row. Same thing goes for the Spacebar actually.

Here is a script I'm using at the same time: http://pastebin.com/YMdJHHA6. I highly advise you getting that script. Use it with your script and you'll exactly see what I'm always talking about. I don't know any other way to explain it.

Comment: The above script DOES send the letter B? Also, if you typed "Hello worldb I'm big" it is not re-enableing it. It's enabled at start, typing "Hello " enables it again since there is a space but since it's already on it does nothing, typing "worldb" disables it since you hit b, typing " I'm " re-enabled it since there is a space (two actually ), typing "big" disables it since you typed a b. Pressing b and space do not toggle the pause. B only disables it and space only enables it.

Comment: I'm going to try alot of things from now on. I'll be back once I found out something new. By the way, thanks for helping me.

Comment: Of course! +1 for effort? Haha! Good luck. I'm on often so if you need any more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Start - nothing happens. 
Press f ==> script sends f until 
a) you press d or ESC
a1) pressed d ==> script sends d until you press f or ESC
a2) pressed ESC ==> script pauses until you press
b1) d ==> sends D
b2) f ==> sends F
b3) ESC ==> sends the last letter sent before.

#include

```
; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{ESC}", "HotKeyPressed")
HotKeySet("f", "HotKeyPressed")
HotKeySet("d", "HotKeyPressed")
HotKeySet("+!d", "HotKeyPressed") ; Shift-Alt-d

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func HotKeyPressed()
    Switch @HotKeyPressed ; The last hotkey pressed.
        Case "{ESC}" ; String is the {PAUSE} hotkey.
            $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
            While $g_bPaused
                Sleep(100)
                ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
            WEnd
            ToolTip("")

        Case "f"
            $g_bPaused = False
            While 1
                Send('F')
                Sleep(500)
            WEnd

        Case "d"
            $g_bPaused = False
            While 1
                Send('D')
                Sleep(500)
            WEnd

        Case "+!d" ; String is the Shift-Alt-d hotkey.
            MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "This is a message.")

    EndSwitch
EndFunc   ;==>HotKeyPressed
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't do what I need. If you tried my script (IF), then you'd actually understand what I'm trying to do. Your script repeatedly sends "F" or "D" when you press it, until you press "ESC". My script (just changed it abit, doesn't matter) sends Q once you press Enter. Not repeatedly, ONCE. So yeah the Pause func works with YOUR script, but not mine.

http://imgur.com/VH3L2s2